# Make plot from 3 columns in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have 3 columns in a dataframe, it looks like this :

```
member_id  quantity  time
a1         2         16-jan-2016
b2         5         16-jan-2016
a1         1         17-jan-2016
b2         10        19-jan-2016
```

and I want to make a graph/plot like this :

[image]

With x-axis is **time**
y-axis is **quantity** 
and each line represents a **member_id**

so far, I use this code :

```
ggplot(df,aes(time,quantity))
```

but it doesn't turn out like I want.
So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(time ,quantity, colour = member_id)) + geom_line()` given your `time` column is of class `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(time,quantity)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=member_id, group=member_id))
```

[More info see here (Mapping variable values to colors)](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/)